# Dispersion Relations (Mathews and Walker,Mathematical methods of Physics, 2nd edition)

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]In page no,131 of Mathews and walker, the function if defined as $$F(x)=\frac{P}{i\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{F(x')}{x'-x}$$
Then, by using even symmetry $$f(-z)=+f^*(z*)$$
they obtained $$F(x)=\frac{P}{i\pi}\int_{\infty}^{0}\frac{F^*(x')}{x'+x}dx'+\frac{P}{i\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{F(x')}{x'-x}dx'$$
I can understand the fact that they decomposed the integral into two parts, but I can see the even symmetry condition applied only to the first integral part, not to the second one. Can please anyone clarify.

Comment: Please note that not everyone has a copy of your book handy, so you will need to supply some definitions. Does $P$ mean the Cauchy principal part? And how does $F$ depend on $f$?

Answer (score 1):

It'd be good if you explained what $z*$ means.

$$
\begin{align}
F(x) &= \frac{P}{i\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{F(x')}{x'-x}dx' \\
&=\frac{P}{i\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{F(x')}{x'-x}dx'+\frac{P}{i\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{F(x')}{x'-x}dx'
\end{align}
$$
doing the change of variable $y=-x'$ in the first integral
$$
\begin{align}
F(x) &=\frac{P}{i\pi}\int_{\infty}^{0}\frac{F(-y)}{-y-x}d(-y)+\frac{P}{i\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{F(x')}{x'-x}dx'\\ 
&=\frac{P}{i\pi}\int_{\infty}^{0}\frac{F(-y)}{y+x}dy+\frac{P}{i\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{F(x')}{x'-x}dx'\\ 
&=\frac{P}{i\pi}\int_{\infty}^{0}\frac{F^*(y*)}{y+x}dy+\frac{P}{i\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{F(x')}{x'-x}dx'
\end{align}
$$
Where in the last line I used the symmetry you mention.

Comment: Why didn't we changed the variable y=-x' in the second integral

Comment: I don't know. Without more knowledge of the subject I can't figure out the intention of the author.

Comment: @RoshanShrestha If you think this answered your question, please click the checkmark on the left hand side of the answer to mark it as the *right answer*.